# Do classical-music performers use editions other than urtext to prepare?

Tags: composition, sheet-music, classical-music, performing

Do any performer of classical music use printed editions of classical works (I mean those that published during the composer's lifetime) other than urtext editions for performing. If this is true, can you name a few?

Answer (score 4):

Most any top classical musician studies a wide variety of available scores, including hand-written copies by the composer, first editions, copies made by the composer's students, and edited version by respected musicians and scholars.

Beyond studying the scores themselves, musicians will study other pieces by the composer -- even for other instruments --any other writing that composer produced (such as diaries and letters), read biographies and other studies of the composer, and travel to cities where the composer had a significant presence -- all in the interest of developing the keenest sense they can of that composer's intentions.